# Swift: Add offline bar for all views such as in facebook messenger

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, reachability

I develop an iOS app which data of it provided by an online server, I'm using [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)  to check availability of internet connection, what I need to do now, create a bar such as in facebook messenger which appear in current (every) UIViewcontroller in my project immediately when there is no internet connection available, How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

**Create your own window to eliminate conditions.**

```
import UIKit
import ReachabilitySwift

class HSWindow: UIWindow {

    let sharedReachability = Reachability()!

    // override point for subclass. Do not call directly
    open override func becomeKey(){

        sharedReachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.removeRechabilityView()
            })
        }

        sharedReachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.addRechabilityView()
            })
        }

        do {
            try sharedReachability.startNotifier()
            print("sharedReachability.startNotifier : Starting.....")
        } catch {
            print("sharedReachability.startNotifier : Unable to start notifier")
        }
    }

    // override point for subclass. Do not call directly
    open override func resignKey(){
        sharedReachability.stopNotifier()
    }
}

//add remove Rechability view
extension HSWindow {
    func addRechabilityView(){
        self.removeRechabilityView()
        let view = HSRechabilityView(); //you any custom view that you want to show on internet connection loss
        self.addSubview(view)

        view.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in //instead of this you can give frame, I have used snapKit here
            make.edges.equalTo(self)
        }
    }

    func removeRechabilityView(){
        for view in self.subviews { //find your view and remove when internet connected 
            if view is HSRechabilityView {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In AppDelegate - didFinishLaunching method**

```
self.window =  HSWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) //user your custom window instead of default one, and this will do all magic without any code
self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

> Let me know if you will anyissue in this flow

Comment: It's great solution but I not need it to overlap navigationbar, I need appear under it such as in facebook messenger, Can I do that in better way, or in any other way instead of "window"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subclassing the `UIWindow`, maybe you can create your `BaseViewController` and all your view controllers inherit it.

In the view controller you can use the safe area to of the `view` property to put your custom view in the right position.

To show that view and present it in all view controller, you can check internet connection and use the `NotificationCenter` to notify all view controllers when network status changes.